# How can I display the form errors under each field?

Tags: python, html, django

I was wondering how can I display the form errors under each field. Considering I have the log in form, if there is a problem with username, then the specific errors should be displayed under, otherwise if there is a problem with the password, the error should be displayed under the password field.
I have been searching for a proper way to do it, this is what I came with:

```html
  <div class="jumbotron">
                    <form class="login" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h4>Log In</h4>
                        <p class="field">{{ form.username }}</p>
                        <p class="field">{{ form.password }}</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log In</button>
                        {% if form.errors %}
                            {% for field in form %}
                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to get into the habit of looping over forms so that you can write generic templates for all forms. So I'd so something like;

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form class="login" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <h4>Log In</h4>

        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <p class="field">{{ field }}</p>
            {% if field.help_text %}
                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {{ field.errors }} {# outputs a UL with class 'errorlist' #}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log In</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

You could then include that form in a template & include it with whatever submit/cancel buttons you wanted.

Comment: I was interpreting form.non_field_errors wrong. This answer helped me finally. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```html
 <div class="jumbotron">
                    <form class="login" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h4>Log In</h4>
                        <p class="field">{{ form.username }}
                        {{ form.username.errors }}
                        </p>
                        <p class="field">{{ form.password }}
                        {{ form.password.errors }}
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What about the non field errros ?

Comment: @DanielCîrstea add this `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to where you want to have it displayed

Comment: still, the errors wont show. When using this: https://pastebin.com/ZScbUKzk I get this: https://i.imgur.com/2bmWClO.png

Comment: There are no errors, but your error blocks are rendering because you're not using a condition on them.

Comment: @markwalker_ I changed it to this: https://pastebin.com/Q6yJdpAq  but problem is, when I enter a wrong username or password, nothing shows... no error .. form just resets itself.

Comment: @DanielCîrstea well in that case it's likely your view, not your template at fault. Ensure you're returning the invalid form in the context so that it's got the errors in it.